# Use of "this" in typescript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working with some refactoring of typescripts clases related with dataContext. The thing is yesterday i spent a lot of time trying figure out why i was not getting a breeze.promise from my new datacontext. finally i got the  solution and it was related with the scope of "this".
Example of bad use of "this":

```
public getSomething(){
  return this.manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(function (data) {               
          //THIS IS NOT WORKING" INSIDE OF THE FUNCTION
            this.log('this log will never be loged :(');
        }
}
```

Now the same code working fine, but using a "that" as temp variable:

```
public getSomething(){
  var that=this;
  return this.manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(function (data) {               
            that.log('get something is complete');
        }
}
```

if you see in abore the second piece of code is working fine, but i have to repeat the process for every method in my class. Now my question is:
How can i create a "that" variable at class level? is that possible?

I tried with the code bellow but i am getting a compilation error:"Could not find symbol 'that'."

```
 export class eventDataContext extends dataContextBase.dataContextBase {
    public that;

    constructor() {        
      super();
      that = this;
    ...
    }
 }
```

any idea how to put this new variable "that" at class level? thank you!

Comment: [JavaScript: Why Understanding Scope And Closures Matter](http://doctrina.org/JavaScript:Why-Understanding-Scope-And-Closures-Matter.html) is a good read

Comment: bind should so the trick https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: thank you @SteveFenton gave me a short a clear answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript has a handy shortcut to solve this problem, called "fat arrow syntax" `=>`

If you use the following, it should work for you:

```
getSomething(){
  return this.manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then((data) => {               
            this.log('This *will* now be logged :)');
        });
}
```

Quick disclaimer - I'm not sure where your `query` is coming from - it isn't passed into the `getSomething` method. If it is a class property, use `this.query`.